# Trying to install requirements.txt in virtual environment and could not find anaconda version 1.7.2

Tags: anaconda, virtualenv, python-venv

I'm trying to install my requirements.txt file into my virtual environment using the command

`pip install -r requirements.txt`

It installs the first package perfectly fine, yet the second (anaconda-client==1.7.2) results in an error that won't allow the pip install to progress. The current version of anaconda-client is 1.2.2 and is native in my virtual environment.
It works on my colleague's computers on macs but not on my windows.

**ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2)) (from versions: 1.1.1, 1.2.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for anaconda-client==1.7.2 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))**

Comment: How do you want to install `anaconda-client==1.7.2` when there are only [versions 1.1.1 and 1.2.2](https://pypi.org/project/anaconda-client/#history)? Not to say that the project seems to be old (2016) and abandoned (the homepage link points to a non-existing repository).

Comment: I wondered that when I go online but when I to ```pip show anaconda-client``` it lists the version as 1.7.2.

And it is what is exported when I do a ```pip freeze >requirements.txt``` the rest of thenon conda modules seem to work fine

Comment: Perhaps you've installed it using conda, miniconda or anaconda: https://anaconda.org/search?q=anaconda-client

Comment: Probably most likely, 
shall I conda install requirements then?

Comment: That's up to you. Some dependencies are available only via `conda`, some only via `pip`, many are available from both. `conda` and `pip` can coexist in one virtual environment.